# how to display odd number post in left side even number post in right side?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php $counter = 3; ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if ( in_category('3') ): ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($counter%2 == 0){echo 'floatRight';} else { echo 'floatLeft'; } ?>  
<?php the_ID(); ?> 
<h1  > <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
<?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?> 
<?php comments_template(); // Get wp-comments.php template ?>
    <?php if($counter%2 == 0){ echo "<div class='clear'></div>";} ?>
    <?php $counter++; ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

i am trying to display in this way and i want to display particular category of post

```
post1

 post2

post3

 post4
```

please give me the solution ...

Comment: Well, the code seems ugly. Do you really need all those `<?php ?>` each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below code.

```
 <?php while(have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php $i++; if(($i % 2) == 0) : $wp_query->next_post(); else : the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endif; endwhile; ?>

    <?php $i = 0; rewind_posts(); ?>

    <?php while(have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php $i++; if(($i % 2) !== 0) : $wp_query->next_post(); else : the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endif; endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Please use get_the_title(); for title

Comment: get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id); --- use this to show your image.

Comment: working fine but showing the message of 
Warning: Missing argument 1 for query_posts()

Answer (score 1):

You can use this css3 property to do it (This would take care odd and even elements, you don't have to write down the loop explicitly):

```
 p:nth-child(odd)   //you can do the same for div
{
float:left; 
}
p:nth-child(even)
{
float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use query_post() or Wp_query() in wordpress . 
Use this code. to get the particular categories post .

```
<?php
// The Query

query_posts( 'cat=3' );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```